# Conditional counting within groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

I wanted to do conditional counting after `groupby`; for example, group by values of column `A`, and then count within each group how often value `5` appears in column `B`.

If I was doing this for the entire `DataFrame`, it's just `len(df[df['B']==5])`. So I hoped I could do `df.groupby('A')[df['B']==5].size()`. But I guess boolean indexing doesn't work within `GroupBy` objects.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 6], 'B': [5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10]})
groups = df.groupby('A')
# some more code
# in the end, I want to get pd.Series({0: 1, 1: 2, 6: 0})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all rows where `B` equals 5, and then apply `groupby/size`:

```
In [43]: df.loc[df['B']==5].groupby('A').size()
Out[43]: 
A
0    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, you could use `groupby/agg` with a custom function:

```
In [44]: df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda ser: (ser==5).sum())
Out[44]: 
A
0    1
4    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Note that generally speaking, using `agg` with a custom function will be slower than using `groupby` with a builtin method such as `size`. So prefer the first option over the second.

```
In [45]: %timeit df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda ser: (ser==5).sum())
1000 loops, best of 3: 927 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit df.loc[df['B']==5].groupby('A').size()
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop
```

---

To include `A` values where the size is zero, you could reindex the result:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 6], 'B': [5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10]})
result = df.loc[df['B'] == 5].groupby('A').size()
result = result.reindex(df['A'].unique())
```

yields

```
A
0    1.0
4    2.0
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: With the first approach, I lose the groups where the conditional count is zero (I updated the example in the question to clarify). I don't know if it's easy to modify it to deal with this. The second approach works perfectly.

Comment: uh.. with my DataFrame, the first approach takes 41 ms, the second takes 10 s! I guess it's the first approach after all, just treating zeroes separately somehow.

Comment: @max I guess the time difference increases as `df[df['B'] == 5]` becomes a smaller subset in the whole dataframe. In order to deal with zeroes, you can get the unique elements from column A with `a = df["A"].unique()` and then use map with the first approach: `pd.Series(a, index = a).map(df.loc[df['B']==5].groupby('A').size()).fillna(0)` Of course it cannot be as fast as the first approach but it should still be much faster than agg/lambda.